# Content on one page disappears after exporting a printable PDF. Acrobat won't print the document

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, export, adobe-acrobat

I created a brochure in InDesign which we need to print. The problem:
I export a digital version, with hyperlinks etc. and everything works fine. But as I export the same file for print using the "High Quality Print" preset, the cover Page won't export properly. An error shows up in Acrobat after opening the file (I'll try to translate it, and will attach a screenshot beneath):

> "There is an error on this Page. Under some circumstances, the page won't be displayed properly in Acrobat. Please contact the author..."
>
> [image: Acrobat Popup]

I tried to add a page before the cover. I also copied the text into Illustrator, created outlines, and copied it back. Than I tried to duplicate the cover and put it at the end of the document. Always the same problem.

I also tried to print the Page, because when I open it with Chrome it's just fine. But by printing with Acrobat, it first pops up that it can't print this document and than that there are no pages selected to be printed.

On the left: InDesign on the left the exported PDF in Acrobat

[image: Incorrect PDF]

Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing the font you use and exporting it again? Possibly a case of corrupted font?

Answer (score 1):

No idea what is wrong with your document, but the likelihood is that some element in your document got corrupted.

Your best bet is to try the standard fixes that usually solve most funky issues with InDesign.

1. First, try exporting the document as an .idml file, then open the .idml file, and try making a PDF from that file. This may be all that you need to do to fix the file. Please note that I don't work with interactive PDFs very often, so I am not sure if the .idml save will retain your interactive elements or not.
2. Try resetting your preferences: Close down InDesign, then reopen it while holding down Ctrl-Alt-Shift (Windows)/Cmd-Opt-Shift (Mac) while InDesign is loading. I keep a backup of my preferences file and screenshots of each of the preference pages saved on my computer, just for this situation.
3. To troubleshoot which page is causing the problem, try deleting a page, resaving the document, and then PDFing the document without that page. If you still have the problem, you know that the page you deleted is okay, so you can try deleting a different page--just make sure to delete one page at a time. It is likely that the corrupted page is the first page, but you never know. Once you have determined which page is causing the issue, you can delete the problem page from your actual project file, add a new page to your document, and recreate the page that caused the problems.

Hopefully one of these options will resolve your issues for you.